# What is the purpose of AND operator in SQL? How do I use AND in my query below?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    c.LastName, 
    c.FirstName, 
    i.InvoiceId, 
    i.CustomerId, 
    i.InvoiceDate, 
    i.BillingCity,
    i.total  
FROM 
    invoices i 
INNER JOIN 
    customers c ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
WHERE 
    BillingCity LIKE 'P%' 
    OR Billingcity NOT LIKE 'D%'
```

I want to know what is the purpose of AND operator and How do I use AND in the query above to find customers from New York who have spent 10$ ?

Comment: BillingCity = 'Newyork' AND total =10

Comment: [docs for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/and-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.LastName, 
    c.FirstName, 
    i.InvoiceId, 
    i.CustomerId, 
    i.InvoiceDate, 
    i.BillingCity,
    i.total  
FROM 
    invoices i 
INNER JOIN 
    customers c ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
WHERE 
    i.BillingCity = 'New York' AND i.total = 10
```

Comment: yes, it sounds like the OP has an order question....so, first is a 'where' then subsequent conditions are an 'and'....piggy backing on @nyanish  answer for an example ...and total = 10 and total<50